# BasicCalculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I would like request for a code review and feedback my calculator web page because I want to improve my coding ability.

Basic calculator

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Basic Calculator</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Basic Calculator</h1>
        
<i>Enter equation by keypad:</i>
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtInputAndResult" onkeypress="return RestrictSpace()">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnMemoryClear" value="MC" onclick="memoryClear()"><input type="button" id="btnMemoryRecall" value="MR" onclick="memoryRecall()"><input type="button" id="btnMemorySubtraction"value="M-" onclick="memorySubstraction()"><input type="button" id="btnMemoryAddition"value="M+" onclick="memoryAddition()"><br>
<input type="button" id="btnClear" value="C" onclick="Clear()"><input type="button" id="btnChangeSign" value="+/-" onclick="changeSign()"><input type="button" id="btnSquareRoot" value="SQRT" onclick="computeSquareRoot()"><input type="button" id="btnPercentage" value="%" onclick="computePercentage()"><br>
<input type="button" id="btnSeven" value="7" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnEight" value="8" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnNine" value="9" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnDivision" value=" / " onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><br>
<input type="button" id="btnFour" value="4" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnFive" value="5" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnSix"  value="6" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnMultiplication" value=" x " onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><br>
<input type="button" id="btnOne" value="1" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnTwo" value="2" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnThree" value="3" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnSubtraction"  value=" - " onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><br>
<input type="button" id="btnZero" value="0" onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnDecimal" value="." onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnEquals" value=" = " onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><input type="button" id="btnAddition" value=" + " onclick="displayCalculation(this)"><br>
    
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        
var key;
var inputString;

key = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult");
inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;

document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").select();

// Input typing catches     
key.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // Cancel the default action, if needed
        event.preventDefault();
        // Trigger the button element with a click
        document.getElementById("btnEquals").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 48 || event.keyCode === 96) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnZero").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 49 || event.keyCode === 97) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnOne").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 50 || event.keyCode === 98) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnTwo").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 51 || event.keyCode === 99) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnThree").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 52 || event.keyCode === 100) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnFour").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 53 || event.keyCode === 101) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnFive").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 54 || event.keyCode === 102) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnSix").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 55 || event.keyCode === 103) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnSeven").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 56 || event.keyCode === 104) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnEight").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 57 || event.keyCode === 105) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnNine").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 191 || event.keyCode === 111) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnDivision").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 88 || event.keyCode === 106) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnMultiplication").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 189 || event.keyCode === 109) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnSubtraction").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 187) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnAddition").click();
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 190) {
        inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
        document.getElementById("btnDecimal").click();
    }
});

function RestrictSpace() {
    if ((event.keyCode > 64 && event.keyCode < 91) || (event.keyCode > 96 && event.keyCode < 123) || event.keyCode === 32) {
        return false;
    }
}

function memoryClear() {
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = "";
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").select();
}

function Clear() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    if (lastNumber == " ") {
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 3);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").select();
    } else {
        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").select();
    }

    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
}

function changeSign() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    if (Math.sign(lastNumber) == -1) {
        lastNumber = lastNumber * -1;
        lastNumSlice = lastNumber.toString().length;
        lastNumSlice - parseFloat(lastNumSlice);
        inputString = inputString.join(" ");
        //alert(lastNumSlice);

        inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - lastNumSlice - 1);
        document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + lastNumber;

    } else {
        if (lastNumber !== parseFloat(inputString[0])) {
            lastNumber = lastNumber * -1;
            lastNumSlice = lastNumber.toString().length;
            lastNumSlice = parseFloat(lastNumSlice);
            inputString = inputString.join(" ");
            inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - lastNumSlice);
            document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + " " + lastNumber;
        } else {
            lastNumber = lastNumber * -1;
            lastNumSlice = lastNumber.toString().length;
            lastNumSlice = parseFloat(lastNumSlice);
            inputString = inputString.join(" ");
            inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - lastNumSlice);
            document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + lastNumber;
        }
    }
    /*if (Number.isNaN(lastNumber))
        {
            if (document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value == " ")
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 2);
                    alert("Please enter a number first.");
                }
            else
                {
                    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + " "; 
                }
        }*/
}

function computeSquareRoot() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    lastNumber = Math.sqrt(lastNumber);
    inputString = inputString.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = lastNumber;
}

function memorySubstraction() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    if (Number.isNaN(lastNumber)) {
        lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 3];
        lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    }
    inputString = inputString.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + " - " + lastNumber;
}

function memoryAddition() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    if (Number.isNaN(lastNumber)) {
        lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 3];
        lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    }
    inputString = inputString.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + " + " + lastNumber;
}

function computePercentage() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    lastNumber = lastNumber / 100;
    inputString = inputString.join(" ");
    inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 1);
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + lastNumber;
}

function memoryRecall() {
    var inputString;
    var lastNumber;

    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    if (Number.isNaN(lastNumber)) {
        lastNumber = inputString[inputString.length - 3];
        lastNumber = parseFloat(lastNumber);
    }
    inputString = inputString.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + lastNumber;
}

function calculate(inputString) {
    var result;
    var ctr;

    ctr = 0;
    inputString = inputString.split(" ");
    // Parse equation from the left 
    result = inputString[0];
    result = parseFloat(result);

    while (ctr < inputString.length) {
        var operand;
        var operator;

        operator = inputString[ctr + 1];
        operand = inputString[ctr + 2];
        operand = parseFloat(operand);

        if (Number.isNaN(result)) {
            result = 0;
        }

        if (Number.isNaN(operand)) {
            operand = 0;
        }

        if (operator == "/") {
            result = result / operand;
        }

        if (operator == "x") {
            result = result * operand;
        }

        if (operator == "-") {
            result = result - operand;
        }

        if (operator == "+") {
            result = result + operand;
        }

        ctr = ctr + 2;
    }

    inputString = inputString.join(" ");
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString + result;
}

function displayCalculation(element) {
    var inputString;
    var elementValue;
    var equals;
    var division;
    var multiplication;
    var addition;
    var subtraction;
    var lastOperator;

    division = document.getElementById("btnDivision").value;
    multiplication = document.getElementById("btnMultiplication").value;
    subtraction = document.getElementById("btnSubtraction").value;
    addition = document.getElementById("btnAddition").value;

    elementValue = element.value;
    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").select();
    inputString = document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value;

    lastOperator = inputString[inputString.length - 1];
    if (lastOperator == " ") {
        lastOperator = inputString[inputString.length - 2];
    }

    if (lastOperator == "/" || lastOperator == "x" || lastOperator == "-" || lastOperator == "+") {
        if (elementValue == division || elementValue == multiplication || elementValue == subtraction || elementValue == addition) {
            inputString = inputString.substring(0, inputString.length - 3);
        }

    }

    inputString = inputString + elementValue;

    document.getElementById("txtInputAndResult").value = inputString;
    equals = document.getElementById("btnEquals").value;

    // Call calculate function when input is the equals character " = "
    if (elementValue == equals) {
        calculate(inputString);
    }
}

</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem in your code is `keyCode`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> #### Deprecated
>
> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing code if possible; see the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Browser_compatibility) at the bottom of this page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)</sup>

You should use [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) or [KeyboardEvent.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) insted.

You should also use html5: `<! DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Thank you for the  review @NonStopGreen. I tried the KeyboardEvent.key with the Enter key but it did not work.

Comment: I mean the Enter key code 13 with the KeyboardEvent.key

Comment: @cabpacedilla you didn't read the MDN example. To check if the key is "enter" you need to do this: `event.key === "Enter"`

Comment: @cabpacedilla here you can check all of the keys: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key#Result)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I will update my code and test.